# Sencha Touch bottom bar icons not showing

Tags: css, extjs, sass, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i'm having problems to see the bottom bar icons on a Sencha Touch app.

I'm using compass and scss to style the app.
Actually, after a research i'm using the mixing:

@include pictos-iconmask('home');

to import the icons that are used in the tabbar.

The bar elements are defined i that way:

{
                title: 'FAQ',
                iconCls: 'star'
},

And seems to be well-defined, in Safari the inspector shows the
 -webkit-mask-image:theme_image("default", "pictos/home.png"); property but this is strikethrough. In Chrome the property doesn't appear, what could be the cause of that issue?

[image]

The attached image shows both scenarios, at the top Safari and the property that i mentioned. At bottom the bar without the "broken" placeholder that Safari shows.

I found a solution that increments the icons z-index property, but i tried this with no luck.

The workaround is like this:

```
.x-tabbar > * {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT 1: Someone have any idea?

Comment: can you try to add the icon to a container. It seems it's not been loaded. Simply give the container a cls:"test" and in scss add .test:before{content'/e600'} (whatever the number for the icon in the content of the tab).

Answer (score 1):

In Sencha Touch 2.4.x you need to do the following :

1. Install Rub
2. Compass
3. Navigate into the app home folder (i.e. to the level of the index.html file)
4. In Terminal run `sencha app watch`
5. Open the ***resources/sass/app.scss*** and add the following code:

   ```
   // This is different in 2.4.x. In earlier versions it was pictos-iconmask as you've indicated you tried in the question. 

   @include icon('browser');
   ```
6. Your tab panel item should have the `iconCls` set up like so:

   ```
   {
       .....,
       title: 'Favorites',
       iconCls: 'heart'
   }
   ```

Additional (Optional) Step:

1. Sometimes the `iconCls` has been commented out in the framework (this has happened to me once before). In that case, go to ***AppName/touch/resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/base/mixins/_Class.scss***
2. Search in the file for a line of code that reads :

   ```
   @else if ($name == "star") { @return "S"; }
   ```
3. Uncomment the line if it's been commented.